# How to prevent VSCode from opening same file multiple times?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Assume you have `index.js` and `service.ts` in the side explorer. When I click on `index.js`, it opens in a view `A`. Then I open `service.ts` in a separate view `B` right to the first one and keep the focus in `B` and then click on `index.js` in the sidebar, it also opens in `B`. Can VS Code be configured such that instead of opening the file again, it switches to the already open one?

Additionally, if I really want the file open twice, I could open it a second time by double clicking it or dragging it to the view where it isnt present already.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, try this setting set to `true`:

```
  "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,
```

Comment: It definitely helps in stopping to reopen alreay open files. Nice would be if cursor focus would also move to the revealed file.

Comment: It doesn't know that you want to switch focus away from the sidebar (maybe you want to open other files, etc.) There is an unbound command that can be used to switch focus to that file: workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup